# Efficient upload data from large files into database

Tags: mysql, sql

Good day everyone, i need a suggestion how to efficient upload data from sufficiently large files into mySql database. So i have two files 5,85Gb and 6Gb of data. For uploading i have used `LOAD DATA LOCAL INTO FILE. First file still uploading (for **36hours**). Current index size 7,2 GB. I have two questions :

1) The data is formatted Lile : {string , int, int, int, int}. I do not need this int values, so i created table with one field of type **varchar(128)**, my query is `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE "file" INTO TABLE "tale"` , so will the data be correct(i mean only strings without int fields).

2) Than larger index than larger load time for next. So, an i doing something wrong? I mean, what i need. I need a fast search then in that strings(espicially in last word). So all of the strings cantains exactly 5 words does it makes any sence to put every single words in different column(n rows, 5 columns).

Please, any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Can u drop index for now and recreate index once data is loaded on table. I think this will work.

Recreation of index will take time.